# Remove image upon class load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove an image once a class appears on a page. Please help on what I'm doing wrong with my code, Not to bright in jquery and js. Thanks for any help.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    function blah (){
    if ($(".Stage_lines_id")[0]){ 
        $('img[src*="still_metrix.jpg"]').remove();

    }
      setInterval(blah, 1000 * 1); 
     }

    });
```

Comment: Where are you calling function blah initially? Also what do you mean by appears on page? Is it added later onto the page?

Comment: How and when you call your function is indeed essential to know.

Comment: On document ready blah should start. I have a slider that is still loading. once its done some of its class would appear too. so once those class appear the image I want should also be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code the problem is `blah` is not called on dom ready, the `setInterval` has to happen inside `ready` not inside `blah`.

Also you can clear the interval once the image is removed

You need something like

```
jQuery(function($) {

    function blah (){
        if ($(".Stage_lines_id").length){ 
            $('img[src*="still_metrix.jpg"]').remove();
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }
    var timer = setInterval(blah, 1000 * 1); 

});
```

Comment: Tried this. But it gets this error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready' `

Comment: @user2356555 other than jquery what are the other libraries included in the page

Comment: @user2356555 try the updated solution, because I assume the `$` is not pointing to jQuery library

Comment: never mind no conflict was the solution. Thanks for the help people.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($(".Stage_lines_id").length){ 
    $('img[src*="still_metrix.jpg"]').remove();

}
```

Comment: WHat is the difference? `$(".Stage_lines_id")[0]` or `$(".Stage_lines_id").length`

Answer (score 0):

just run it on an event

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


    $('.Stage_lines_id').each(function(){

        $('img[src*="still_metrix.jpg"]').remove(); //also could use .hide();


     });

});
```